# Redirect back page error after submit form

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

As the title says, when I submit my form ( report system ), I'm redirected back to this link : `https://website.com/career_report_event` - with error but my data are saved in database . Why is this happening? I should be redirected back to the previous page.I added `sleep(5);` to counter 5 seconds after redirect, but now isn't working anymore.

*Here is my code:*

```
public function careerReportEvent(requ $request)

 {


$reportExists = \App\Reports::where('user_id', $request['user_id'])
         ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString())
         ->exists();

         if($reportExists) {
         // report has been created within 5 minutes
         return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error', 'Report created within the last 5 minutes']);
     }

     $lastReport = \App\Reports::where('user_id', $request['user_id'])
                                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                                ->first();


$lastReportOn = time() - \Carbon\Carbon::parse($lastReport->created_at)->timestamp;

    if($lastReportOn < 150 ) {
        // report has been created within 5 minutes
        sleep(5);
        return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'This action was blocked as too many reports were sent in a short amount of time. Please try later.');
    }
     $report = \App\Reports::create([
                     'user_id' => $request['user_id'],
                     'username' => $request['username'],
                     'user_id_posted' => $request['user_id_posted'],
                     'username_posted' => $request['username_posted'],
                     'career_solution_id' =>$request['career_solution_id'],
                     'subject' =>$request['subject'],
                     'why_reporting' =>$request['why_reporting'],
                     'why_reporting_message' =>$request['why_reporting_message'],
                     'additional_message' =>$request['additional_message'],
                     'comment' =>$request['comment'],
                     'comment_user' =>$request['comment_user'],
                     'comment_id' =>$request['comment_id'],
                   ]);
                   $id = $request['career_solution_id']; // looks like this is the ID you ar looking for

                   $event = Event::findOrfail($id);
                   $event->active = $request['active'];
                   $event->save();

                   if ($user = Sentinel::check())
                  {

                        $data = $this->data;
                         $user_id = $user->id;
                     // return $request->all();





                                 $career_solution = \App\CareerSolution::findOrFail($user_id);

                                  $log = \App\Log::create([
                                 'user_id' => $request['user_id_posted'],
                                 'log' => $request->title,
                                 'date' => time(),
                                 'article_type' => 'event',
                                 'type' => 'report',
                                 'formatted_date' => date_format(date_create(date('Y-m-d')),"F dS, Y"),
                                 'link' => $request['subject'],
                                 'action_user_id' => $user_id,
                                 'action_name' => $user->name,
                                 'action_username' => $user->username,
                                 'item_id' => $request['career_solution_id'],
                                 'profile_picture' => $request['profile_picture']

                             ]);
                             $id = $request['career_solution_id'];
                             $news = News::findOrfail($id);

                             $news_user = User::findOrfail($news->user_id);

                          $my_alerts = \App\MyAlert::where('user_id','=',$news->user_id)->first();
                          if(isset($my_alerts))
                          {
                             if(($my_alerts->report == 1) && ($my_alerts->email_frequency == 1))
                             {

                                 $message = "";
                                 $message .= "<table style='width:100%'>";
                                 $message .= "<tr>";
                                 $message .= "<td style='width:40%'>";
                                 $message .= "<img src='".asset('assets/img/WS_logo.png')."' height='35' width='185'>";
                                 $message .= "</td><td>";
                                 $message .= "</td><td style='float:right;'>";
                                 $message .= date('F jS, Y');
                                 $message .= "</td></tr></table><hr><br>";

                                 $message .= "</td></tr><tr align='center'>";
                                 $message .= "<td>If you do not wish to receive this messages, access your Workstickers acoount / Alerts Section and disable it.</td></tr>";
                                 $message .= "<tr align='center'><td><img src='".asset('assets/img/font-image/share_facebook.png')."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='".asset('assets/img/font-image/skype-icon.png')."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='".asset('assets/img/font-image/linkedin.png')."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='".asset('assets/img/font-image/googleplus_icon.png')."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='".asset('assets/img/font-image/twitter_icon.jpg')."'></td></tr>";


                                 Mail::send('send', ['content' => $message], function ($m) use ($news_user,$user)
                                 {
                                     $m->from('hello@workstickers.com', "Workstickers");
                                     $m->to($news_user->email, $news_user->name)->subject("Workstickers alert : ".$user->username." has reported one of your articles.");
                                 });
                             }

                   }
                  }

     if($report != ""){
       sleep(5);
         flash('Career solution report submited', 'success');
     }else{
         flash('Career solution report', 'warning');
     }



     return Redirect::back();


 }
```

*Here is my route:*

```
Route::post('career_report_event', 'CareerSolutionController@careerReportEvent');
```

Comment: Which error shows after redirect?

Comment: Page not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should save the previous url in your form, send it to your controller and in your controller returned on this url.

Code form

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{ URL::previous() }}">
```

code controller

```
return redirect($request->url);
```

Comment: Do you need that on your controller
``
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function careerReportEvent(Request $request) {}

``

Comment: I'm using `use Illuminate\Http\Request as requ;`

Comment: When you dd($request->url); what does he tell you?

Comment: nothing happens at `   dd($request->url);
     return redirect($request->url);`, maybe I didn't put the return in correct position?

Comment: your input URL must be in the form!

Comment: it is in the form, with hidden type.

Comment: is that you forgot something because in your controller if you put everything in the beginning of your function must have something in $request

Comment: Version laravel plz.

Comment: my version is 5.2

Comment: try to : return `redirect()->to('/home');`

Comment: nah...same..., maybe is because I have other returns before that? like here `        return Redirect::back()->with('error', 'This action was blocked as too many reports were sent in a short amount of time. Please try later.');
`

Comment: for that I tell you to put the dd above and put the redirect ´return redirect($request->url);´ all over at the beginning of your function

Comment: Well, if I put the code at the beginning I got at `dd` the previous link. - "https://mylink.com/view-event/1880_report"

Comment: So now move the dd and try first in your function the return I gave you and you'll see if it's good and no mistake.

Comment: Now it just returns me on the previous page, but now the other functions doesn't works. Like this: `   if($reportExists) {
         // report has been created within 5 minutes
         return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['error', 'Report created within the last 5 minutes']);
     }`, here, should redirect to a page with error, if I make a report within the last 5 minutes.

Comment: i prefere this 
´´
Session::flash('error', 'yourerrorhere');
return redirect($request->url);
``
try this on your if, no miss use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have import the right namespace before like this

```
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
```

in your code you can write

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: try return back();

Comment: nope...maybe the position of `return back();` is wrong, I put it under `if($report != ""){ ....`